# Error Mapping Geometry type Point in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

Problem when mapping an entity with a geometric field Geometry Point. When accessing the table repository, using the standard function findAll() getting "null" , although there are records in the database.When configuring, I used the official manual Hybernate Spatial. I get an error when requesting a controller: " **exception is org.geolatte.geom.codec.WkbDecodeException: Expected geometryKeyword starting at position: 0] with root cause"** Help me please , I do not know how to act and what is the reason

My config:

1. Hibernate (5.4.32.Final)
2. Hibernate Spatial (5.4.32.Final)
3. Posgis (version 2.5)
4. PostgreSQL 10.17

Entity:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Data
@Entity
@Table (name = "region",
        indexes = { @Index(name = "description_index",columnList = "description"),
                    @Index(name = "region_name_key",columnList = "name",unique = true),
                    @Index(name = "region_pkey", columnList = "region_id",unique = true) } )

public class Region  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "region_id")
    private Integer region_id;

    @Column(name = "state_id")
    private Integer state_id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "location") // problem field mapping, causing the problem
    private Point location ;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

}
```

Service:

```
import java.util.List;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegionService implements RegionServiceImpl {

    private final RegionRepository regionRepository;
    private final RegionMappingUtils regionMappingUtils;

    @Override
    public List<RegionDTO> findAll() {

        ArrayList<RegionDTO> convert_objects = new ArrayList<>();

        RegionDTO conv_object;

        List<Region> objects = regionRepository.findAll();

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {

            conv_object = regionMappingUtils.mapToRegionDto(objects.get(i));

            convert_objects.add(conv_object);
        }
        return convert_objects;
    }}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RegionRepository extends JpaRepository <Region,Integer> {


}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service</name>
    <description>Table access service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc-jtsparser</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vividsolutions/jts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
            <version>1.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Aplication.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=**********

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

Error occurred:

```
2021-07-27 10:19:05.634  INFO 10280 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.axsoft.service.entity.Server_interface$Server_interface_pkey (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2021-07-27 10:19:05.903  INFO 10280 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-07-27 10:19:05.903  INFO 10280 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-07-27 10:19:06.335  WARN 10280 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-07-27 10:19:06.582  INFO 10280 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-27 10:19:06.588  INFO 10280 --- [           main] com.axsoft.service.ServiceApplication    : Started ServiceApplication in 2.88 seconds (JVM running for 3.611)
2021-07-27 10:19:21.676  INFO 10280 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-27 10:19:21.681  INFO 10280 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-27 10:19:21.681  INFO 10280 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
2021-07-27 10:19:22.293 ERROR 10280 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.geolatte.geom.codec.WkbDecodeException: Expected geometryKeyword starting at position: 0] with root cause

org.geolatte.geom.codec.WkbDecodeException: Expected geometryKeyword starting at position: 0
    at org.geolatte.geom.codec.BaseWktParser.matchesGeometryKeyword(BaseWktParser.java:103) ~[geolatte-geom-1.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.geolatte.geom.codec.BaseWktParser.matchesGeometryTaggedText(BaseWktParser.java:64) ~[geolatte-geom-1.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.geolatte.geom.codec.BaseWktParser.parse(BaseWktParser.java:54) ~[geolatte-geom-1.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.geolatte.geom.codec.PostgisWktDecoder.decode(PostgisWktDecoder.java:42) ~[geolatte-geom-1.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.geolatte.geom.codec.WktDecoder.decode(WktDecoder.java:44) ~[geolatte-geom-1.8.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.parseWkt(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.java:76) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.toGeometry(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.java:67) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(PGGeometryTypeDescriptor.java:146) ~[hibernate-spatial-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3131) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1863) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1791) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1764) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1616) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:740) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2843) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2825) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2657) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1636) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:396) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy103.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.axsoft.service.service.RegionService.findAll(RegionService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.axsoft.service.controllers.regionController.gettingTable(regionController.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

Database type:[image]

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Try removing the `postgis-jdbc-jtsparser` and `postgis-jdbc` dependencies. They might be interfering with Hibenate Spatial.

Comment: removing the specified dependencies did not change anything, the error persisted, I give the full stack of errors ( made changes to question, added full stack) please look

Comment: Clearly, Hibernate Spatial is not expecting the type of values that are stored in your table.  I suggest you setup a new empty database, configure Hibernate to generate the schema automatically, and store some data in it using your application. Then compare the database differences.

Comment: I thought of something else. You don't have by any change a table with these types: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-geometry.html? These are not Postgis and not supported by Hibernate Spatial

Comment: are you saying that this type is simply not supported by spatial hibernation? it looks strange, especially if you look at the official manual. what then to do with the Point type? how to work with it?

Comment: may be  create a custom type?

Comment: which type to choose?

Comment: No, I mean there are two type hierarchies for spatial. Those provided by Postgresql and those provided by Postgis. The Hibernate Spatial types only work with those from Postgis.

Comment: if I want to work with the specified data as an internal geometry, do I need to write my own type in which the Postgre point type is converted to postgis geometry?

Comment: how to display entity field if Point posgres type is not supported by spatial hibernation? that's the main question

Comment: For now you have to write your own type. Support for Postgresql native geometry types is coming (see issue [HHH-14140](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14140). But the work for Hibernate 6 currently has priority.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot in a difficult situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the column in database for location from type of `point` to type `geometry`

Also use all the following properties

```
spring:
 jpa:
   properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
   database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
   hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
```

Comment: the problem is that I would like to save the data in the database exactly as it is now, that is, in the Point type. changing types is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

In this situation You can do: assign definition of column as geography,

```
@Column(name = "location", columnDefinition="geography")
private Point location;
```

set hibernate dialect and database-platform as:

> org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

It will help you!